# TFS 2012 Restoration-based Move - Unexpected Outcome

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, tfs

**The goal:** decom the old server where TFS/SQL was originally installed, and run TFS/SQL on new server. *To add **insult to injury**, the old server I will reference here is **SBS 2011** - if you know anything about that environment, you may understand why it is slated for decom.*

I performed a **restoration-based move** last week. While **it was successful** with respect to functionality, I now have what I would describe as a dual data + application tier implementation. Today, I have **TFS/SQL installed on two servers**, both with TFS Version: 11.0.60610.1 (Tfs2012.Update3) and SQL Version: 2008R2. Both servers in the same domain.

My curiosity lies in the behavior of the Tfs_Configuration db. I **restored both the Tfs_ db as well as the Tfs_Configuration db (via .BAK files) to the new SQL server**, but I still see activity happening on the old server here "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier\Web Services_tfs_data", but no updated/recent files in the same location on the new server, suggesting the Tfs_Configuration db really did not move/restore properly.

In the TFS console on the new server, I see the URLs in the **“Application Tier Summary**” section referring to the old server, but the Machine Name is the new server. I also see in the "**Application Tiers**" section, a reference to the old server Machine name. Yet, in verifying change logs, the Tfs_ db is now resident on the new server and accepting Visual Studio commits/check-ins. There is a Tfs_Configuration db on the new server, but it seems to be the default install copy and not my restored db.

In the various guides I have read, I do understand the **web.config** file holds the instructional set for the catalog, etc. here *"appSettings … add key="applicationDatabase" value="Data Source=instance name;Initial Catalog=Tfs_Configuration;Integrated Security=True"*.  I was expecting to change that entry once it migrated to the new server, but rather it is still parked on the old server.

*I have turned off the TFS and SQL services on the old server as a trial to see if the new installation would pick up the load, but as you might expect, TFS then goes into an unavailable state to the users.*

**The primary questions are:**

1. Why did the Tfs_Configuration db not restore to the new server in the same fashion as the Tfs_ db?
2. How can I move that Tfs_Configuration db and turn off that old SBS 2011 unit?

Any tips or tricks are welcomed and appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is a non trivial operation (see [Move Team Foundation Server from One Hardware Configuration to Another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms404869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Typical missing steps:

- Changing URLs
- Cleaning caches
- [Changing server ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349259.aspx) if you want to keep both instances live
- [Changing accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in case you used local user accounts

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this process successfully. It required a triangulation between the three servers. The essential aspects involved solid SQL backups, coupled with the settings.xml from healthy TFS Console backups.

It was certainly a process that took a lot of planning and anticipating snags.

All-in-all, it was a great exercise in watching the data flow and understanding the roles of the configuration and collection DBs. Thank you for responding to my inquiry.